Rough Idle and RPM drop Only When in Drive(or Reverse) with AC On
2010 Ford Escape 2.5L
I've noticed that when the AC is on, the car idles very rough only when in gear (Drive, Reserve, etc.). If it's in park or neutral and the motor is running perfectly, also when I drive it without AC it runs fine no shaking at all. When I drive it high RPMs with the AC on I don't notice the motor shaking, but when I'm parked or stopped at a red light it shakes and stalls sometimes.
It was around 92K miles and this is the only issue it has. The A/C always runs perfectly cool in any gear.
So far I've:
Changed the alternator
Cleaned MAF sensor
Cleaned Throttle body
PS: Does not have an IAC.
Can anyone help me with this issue? Any idea what it might be?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I found the solution! I Changed the ignition coils and spark plugs and it solve the rough idling issue, its now is running perfectly.
